# How to check the type of a value from a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get the type of the value stored in a `JSONObject`.

```
String jString = {"a": 1, "b": "str"};
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jString);
```

Is it possible to get the type of the value stored at key `"a"`; 
 something like `jObj.typeOf("a") = java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: If you want more control over JSON parsing, use some other parser than `org.json`, such as Jackson.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can get the object from the JSON with the help of [`JSONObject.get()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method and then using the `instanceof` operator to check for the type of Object.

Something on these lines:-

```
String jString = "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": \"str\"}";
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jString);
Object aObj = jObj.get("a");
if (aObj instanceof Integer) {
    // do what you want
}
```

Comment: Note that it may be `Integer` or `Long`; `Float` or `Double`.

Comment: hehe, I have some mythic example for this case: 
I have two same JSONObject {"visits":4880502, ... }, but when I get this field by object.get("visits") I have :

object1 val: 4880502.0 | class java.lang.Double
object2 val: 4880502 | class java.lang.Integer

Comment: Does gson have a similar functionality? Their documentation doesn't seem to specify anything regarding getting the type of a particular field.

Answer (score 10):

The best solution is to use [`JSONObject.get()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) and check for the type using `instanceof` operator.

Comment: You can use this kind of approach for each type you need, catching the appropriate exceptions

Comment: 1st approach, throwing exception, is bit costly in terms of resource, and should be avoided, especially if used on resource critical devices. (mobile/tabs)

Comment: @baraky Thank you for answer but I'm trying to avoid additional libraries.

Comment: @Ungureanu Liviu it was just a typo :)

Comment: @baraky ah, I missed your edit: I saw GSONObject.get() version. Sorry about that. Thank you :)

Comment: This is just what @RainMaker said, but with less detail.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `JSONObject.get()` may return an integer as either  `java.lang.Integer` or `java.lang.Long`, for example, for `{a:3,b:100300000000}` we see

```
D/+++     ( 5526): +++a=>class java.lang.Integer:3
D/+++     ( 5526): +++b=>class java.lang.Long:100300000000
```

I use the code like (note that we use types `long` and `double` instead of `int` and `float`, and that in my task there may be ***no nested `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`*** so they are not supported):

```
    for (String k : new AsIterable<String>(json.keys())) {
            try {
                    Object v = json.get(k);
        //Log.d("+++","+++"+k+"=>"+v.getClass()+":"+v);
                    if (v instanceof Integer || v instanceof Long) {
                            long intToUse = ((Number)v).longValue();
                            ...
                    } else if (v instanceof Boolean) {
                            boolean boolToUse = (Boolean)v).booleanValue();
                            ...
                    } else if (v instanceof Float || v instanceof Double) {
                            double floatToUse = ((Number)v).doubleValue();
                            ...
                    } else if (JSONObject.NULL.equals(v)) {
                            Object nullToUse = null;
                            ...
                    } else {
                            String stringToUse = json.getString(k);
                            ...
                    }
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("exc: "+e2);
                    e2.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

where `AsIterable` lets us use the `for(:)` loop with an iterator and is defined as:

```
public class AsIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    public AsIterable(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return iterator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why String is not casted to string and you use the getString method again?

Answer (score 3):

I found this way to find data type of element value in JSON / Json. It's working very fine for me.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                Iterator<String> iterator = json.keys();

                if (iterator != null) {
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iterator.next();
                        Object value = json.get(key);
                        String dataType = value.getClass().getSimpleName();

                        if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("Integer")) {
                            Log.i("Read Json", "Key :" + key + " | type :int | value:" + value);

                        } else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("Long")) {
                            Log.i("Read Json", "Key :" + key + " | type :long | value:" + value);

                        } else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("Float")) {
                            Log.i("Read Json", "Key :" + key + " | type :float | value:" + value);

                        } else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("Double")) {
                            Log.i("Read Json", "Key :" + key + " | type :double | value:" + value);

                        } else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("Boolean")) {
                            Log.i("Read Json", "Key :" + key + " | type :bool | value:" + value);

                        } else if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("String")) {
                            Log.i("Read Json", "Key :" + key + " | type :string | value:" + value);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This helps me!  ```String dataType = value.getClass().getSimpleName();``` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse all the data as `String` and then try to convert it to the desired type. At this point you may catch the exception and determine which type is the parsed data.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is not working for me. In the latest version to get the data type of the field dynamically, instead of using `JSONObject.get` what you can do is get it as `JsonPrimitive` like

`JsonPrimitive value = json.getAsJsonPrimitive('key');`

Now you can call

`value.isNumber()`
`value.isBoolean()`
`value.isString()`

Comment: instead using `JSONObject` if we use `JsonObject` we can do above thing