# Schema aware JsonPath library?

Tags: java, .net, json, jsonpath, json-schema-validator

I am currently using the Jayway JsonPath implementation to pull data out of various JSON files. The problem here is that all the data is then returned as Strings leaving me to guess what type the data should be.

I would like to do is find a library that takes a JSON file and validates against a JSON schema. From there I want all of my JSON path expressions to return typed data for to use inside my application.

I know this can be done for XML using libraries like Saxon, but I want to know if anyone has found a JSON equivalent?

An ideal library would be available in both Java and .NET, but one that is only available in Java would be adequate.

Comment: For the first part of your question (Validate json against a schema), have a look at [this](http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/). I have tried it and it works like a charm. For the second part of your question (determining data type of a jsonpath expression value), I currently do not have a definite answer.

Comment: For the second part, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject). I did not recommend it in my previous comment since it does not return a definite datatype (an `int` could be returned as `long` and so on), and also it does not take into consideration the schema. But if your data is relatively simple, you could use this.

Comment: I was really hoping for something that did typing based on the schema, but that might work.