# How to know whether my json value is boolean or String value contain

Tags: android, json

In my json I'm getting one key in which sometime it may come with String value or may be it will be Boolean value how to determine what value it come.

JSON with String

```
{
  "status" : "success",
   "next" : "0.1"
}
```

Same JSON with Boolean

```
{
  "status" : "success",
   "next" : false
}
```

How will I come to know the "next" key contain String or Boolean value?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject)

Comment: optString and optBoolean one of has value and one is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one

```
Object value = json.get("next");

if(value instanceof Boolean){
    boolean booValue = json.getBoolean("next");
}else {
    String str = json.getString("next");
}
```

Comment: error message java.lang.object cannot cast to boolean