# Determine user input data-type dynamically in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I've written the following code to determine the data-type of input entered by the user.

**Update**: Removed parsing into `Float` since a `Double` value can also be parsed into `Float` at cost of some precision as mentioned by @DodgyCodeException

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        System.out.println("Enter input:");
        input = src.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered:" + getDataType(input));
    }

    private static String getDataType(Object input) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject((String) input);
            return "JSONObject";
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(input);
                return "JSONArray";
            } catch (JSONException ex0) {
                try {    
                    Integer inti = Integer.parseInt((String) input);
                    return "Integer";
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex1) {
                    try {                          
                            Double dub = Double.parseDouble((String) input);
                            return "Double";
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex3) {
                            return "String";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've to run this repeatedly hundreds of time and I've read catching `Exception` is an expensive operation.
Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: It may not be as much of a performance issue as you think - "hundreds" of times isn't much, and after a while of throwing the same exception, the Oracle VM will (by default) omit the stack trace generation, which is the expensive bit. Have you run a microbenchmark to see if you have any issues?

Comment: sidenote: hundreds of times is nothing to a cpu

Comment: Have you tried, where is possible, with instanceof?

Comment: @TimCastelijns okay..I'll update the question..how about thousands...or number-of-iterations-when-it-actually-starts-to-matter

Comment: that's the wrong way to go about it. You don't have to optimize everything you write. Especially not prematurely

Comment: You seem to be casting to `String` willy-nilly without catching `ClassCastException`. If you know it's definitely a String, why not make the argument a String?

Comment: A successful parse as a `float` doesn't mean the number can't be a `double` with better precision. The parse as a `float` would simply throw away the extra unrepresentable precision existing in the string. You're better off always parsing as `double`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'll remember that, thnx

Comment: I guess you can go for instanceOf() method. You can one with int (if you dont have any higher values else long) for all the numbers, String for words ,Boolean for boolean and Character for characters instead of looping in the exceptions. My approach would ultimately need four if clauses. Hope it helps !!

Comment: @Jayanth you should have read other answers first, sorry but `instanceOf` doesn't help.

Comment: @Jayanth Also, nitpick - but `instanceof` is a Java keyword rather than a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach would be to let the framework do its thing, and use it to parse the input a generic way:

```
Object obj = new org.json.JSONTokener(input).nextValue();
if (obj instanceof JSONArray)
    return "JSONArray";

if (obj instanceof JSONObject)
    return "JSONObject";

if (obj instanceof Integer)
    return "Integer"
...
```

Perhaps use a `switch` statement or a `Map` instead of a long list of `if` constructs. And catch `JSONException` for input that is not valid JSON.

Could perhaps be simplified to return `obj.getClass()` or `obj.getClass().getSimpleName()` for almost identical functionality to what you have now.

Comment: Your answer is by far best I suppose, I saw at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject/15920281#15920281) answer which is a slight variation of what you said above.
I also checked [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) but that seems to be too much of hard work for this rather simple task.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I don't like the idea of determining the type by parser's exceptions. I would build a pattern for each format and iterate over all of them to check if the given string matches one of them.

It's similar how the `Scanner` class works, but it's quite complicated. It's difficult to write the regular expressions which should cover all the possible cases.

But if the regexes are prepared, the algorithm is straightforward:

```
public class Main {

    private final Map<String, String> patterns = Map.of(
            "Integer", integerPattern()
    );

    public String getDataType(String input) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : patterns.entrySet()) {
            if (Pattern.matches(entry.getValue(), input)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }

}
```

Here is an interesting part - an example of `integerPattern()`. I have taken it from `Scanner` and simplified it a bit:

```
private String integerPattern() {
    String radixDigits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(0, 10);
    String digit = "((?i)[" + radixDigits + "]|\\p{javaDigit})";
    String groupedNumeral = "(" + "[\\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]" + digit + "?" + digit + "?(" +
            "\\," + digit + digit + digit + ")+)";
    String numeral = "((" + digit + "++)|" + groupedNumeral + ")";
    String javaStyleInteger = "([-+]?(" + numeral + "))";
    String negativeInteger = "\\-" + numeral + "";
    String positiveInteger = "" + numeral + "";
    return "(" + javaStyleInteger + ")|(" +
            positiveInteger + ")|(" +
            negativeInteger + ")";
}
```

I am pretty sure you can google all the regexes or find them in here.

But what if there is a "lighter" solution or you simply don't want to use a regex approach?

You can mix up different techniques by introducing a `Map<String, Predicate<String>>`:

```
class Main {

    private final Map<String, Predicate<String>> predicates = Map.of(
            "Integer", this::isInteger,
            "JSON", this::isJSON
    );

    public String getDataType(String input) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Predicate<String>> predicate : predicates.entrySet()) {
            if (predicate.getValue().test(input)) {
                return predicate.getKey();
            }
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }

    private boolean isJSON(String input) {
        return LibraryClass.isJSON(input);
    }

    private boolean isInteger(String input) {
        try {
            Integer.valueOf(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I believe it's more readable, it decreases the level of nesting and encapsulates different logic in separate methods.

Comment: I saw one question on SO which was using regex to determine `Integer` or `Double`

Comment: Regexes are invariably a "nicer" way of determining this, but won't yield the same exact results as above and may be slower in many cases - I think it's worth clarifying this since the original question focused on performance.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know whether input is a json/jsonarray or not.

You need to handle the `JSONException` to determine the JSON type and then you can use [NumberFormat parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method to determine the other types as shown below:

```
    private static String getDataType(String input) {
       try {
            return getJsonObjectType(input);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            try {
                return getJsonArrayType(input);
            } catch (JSONException ex2) {
                   return getNonJsonType(input);
           }
       }
    }

    private static String getJsonArrayType(String input) throws JSONException {
        new JSONArray(input);
        return "JSONArray";
    }

    private static String getJsonObjectType(String input) throws JSONException {
        new JSONObject((String) input);
        return "JSONObject";
    }

    private static String getNonJsonType(String input) {
        try {
             return getNumberType(input);
         } catch(ParseException ex3) {
             return "String";
         }
    }

    private static String getNumberType(String input) throws ParseException {
         Number number = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(input);
         if(number instanceof Long) {
             if(number.longValue() < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                 return "int";
             } else {
                 return "long";
             }
         } else {
             if(number.doubleValue() < Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                 return "float";
             } else {
                 return "double";
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using `JSON` because I want to know whether it is a json/jsonarray or not.

Comment: Your code is potentially throwing away the precision of a `double` by returning "float". Consider an input such as 3.1415926536 which will return "float" even though a float can't hold that much precision. You're better off always returning `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The long and short of it is:

- There's no sensible way to encapsulate this exact functionality while not catching those exceptions.
- If you're talking about running that method "hundreds" of times, it really shouldn't be a performance bottleneck. If it is, then benchmark it, work out where the bottlenecks are in that method, and then address those specifically.

For completion though, there's *similar* things you can accomplish without catching those exceptions - though please bear in mind I've done no benchmarks, and **these results may or may not be faster in your case!**

For working out if something's JSON, [there's a `mayBeJSON()` method in JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html#mayBeJSON%28java.lang.String%29), but it's a rather outdated library (last updated 2010.)

If you want to know whether something will fit in an int specifically, then there's no other sensible way than catching the NFE off `parseInt()` really. However, if you just want to know whether something is a number, you could just use a regex:

```
str.matches("\\d+"); //Returns true if it's a whole positive number
str.matches("-?\\d+"); //Returns true if it's a whole number
```

(Other regexes are easily calculated / found online for decimal numbers, numbers with exponents, etc.)

Or you could stream it, and check each character individually:

```
str.chars().allMatch(c->Character.isDigit(c));
```

Alternatively, you may wish to prepend or replace your exception checks with [NumberUtils.isCreateable()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-) from Apache Commons (`isParseable()`, and other methods on that class may also be of use.)

Comment: I tried to look into the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.java) for implementation of `isParseable()` method but I couldn't find it, is it deprecated now?

Comment: @Kainix - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#line.1533

Comment: the javadoc of that function did say that it won't parse hexadecimal values but if we pass `2.4f` which is parsable but it will return `false` due to `Character.isDigit()` condition check, which isn't desirable.

Comment: @Kainix Yes, it's not a perfect replacement at all - it entirely depends on what you're trying ot achieve as to what would work / wouldn't work for your use case.