# how to find value data type from a string?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am reading data from a file. So the only way to read each of the line as a String[]. One of the line is like following one.

```
String[] row = new String[10];
row[0] = "hey";
row[1] = "10";
row[2] = "3.1415";
row[3] = "true";
row[4] = null;
row[5] = "2020-01-01";
row[6] = "";
```

Here the goal is i have to screen each cell value of a row and find which data type it is. (Eg:- "hey" is string, "true" is boolean, "10" is integer/long, "2020-01-01" is date).

do we have any methods to find value data type like getClass().getName() and instance of datatype to find variable type.

Thanks, help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Integer.valueOf` `Double.valueOf` etc.  Dates will be difficult

Comment: The data type of all those values is ... `String`!! --- Yeah, they are all valid strings. What other data types do you need to identify? Without an explicit list *(`Integer`? `Long`? `BigInteger`? `Float`? `Double`? `BigDecimal`? All the above? When to choose which, since `"10"` fits them all?)*, incl. valid format *(e.g. do numbers allow 1000-separators? NaN? Infinity? Spelled or as `∞` symbol?)*, the question is **too broad**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine user input data-type dynamically in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683126/determine-user-input-data-type-dynamically-in-java)

Comment: You can define pattern for each type using regular expression, like string with numbers without decimal is integer or long.