# What is the best way to filter out a Json field if its of a specific type?

Tags: android, gson

In an Android (Java) environment and I'm using Gson to handle serialization/deserialization. In one of the GET requests I'm making, the API returns either a boolean or an object for a field "keyName". How do I ignore this field when the value is a boolean?

I tried using a User Defined Exclusion Strategy, but I don't think it can be used to ignore a specific type.

```
public class MovieAccountState {

@SerializedName("rated")
private Rating mRated;
@SerializedName("watchlist")
private boolean mWatchlisted;

public Rating getRated() {
    return mRated;
}

public boolean isWatchlisted() {
    return mWatchlisted;
}
}
```

*Edit: There is not too much relevant code to post, Gson handles the creation of objects from Json for me, so the field "rated" from the api either has a boolean or an object. If there is a way for me to intercept the Json data before Gson creates the objects.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: using different types for the same field is bad in general. *Best* is opinion based, but most people opinion here will be that the *best* way to fix it is to use different fields for that.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I don't have control over the API, its a third party service. I have to find a solution on the client.

Comment: Also you can create a custom deserializer for your model class, so you will manually deserialize this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way is the try-catch

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("keyName");
} catch(JSONException e) {
    // Do Nothing or something else
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution for the situation. BUT using the same key name for boolean and object is bad. You should change the keys.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I don't have control over the API, its a third party service.

Comment: Well in that case this is the best thing you can do.

Comment: Keep in mind that this snippet can be used also in case the key is not defined in the json response

Comment: Just a small improvement of checking a type instead of try..catch,a s it is better to avoid exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15920281/1568530

Comment: I think that checking the object type is not efficent in this case because you need to declare a generale Object, then check is type and finally casting it into JSONObject. With my solution you don't need to do all this stuff. If the value type is correct you can continue without spending time on a IF statement, else you have to catch the exception and continue.

Comment: I have used a combination of your answers and took @VladyslavMatviienko advice on using JsonDeserializer, thanks to both of you.