# Is JsonElement integer or float?

Tags: java, gson

Is it possible to determine whether a GSON `JsonElement` instance is an integer or is it a float?

I'm able to determine whether it's a number:

```
JsonElement value = ...
boolean isNumber = value.getAsJsonPrimitive().isNumber();
```

But how to determine if it's an integer or a float, so I can subsequently use the correct conversion method? Either

```
float f = value.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsFloat();
```

or

```
int i = value.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt();
```

Edit: The other question may answer why this may be not implemented in GSON, but this question definitely isn't its duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Gson from expressing integers as floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507997/how-to-prevent-gson-from-expressing-integers-as-floats)

Comment: @lucidbrot I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: quoting: "Since JSON doesn't distinguish between integer and floating point fields Gson has to default to Float/Double for numeric fields.". Sounds to me like exactly what you're asking about

Comment: @lucidbrot I see this answer as being orthogonal to my question. Whatever the way Gson defaults numbers, there could be a way of it answering whether the number essentially "contains a dot" or not.

Comment: Okay, then great you've clarified that it's not a dupe

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found so far is using regex on a string:

```
if (value.getAsJsonPrimitive().isNumber()) {
    String num = value.getAsString();
    boolean isFloat = num.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+");
    if (isFloat)
        System.out.println("FLOAT");
    else
        System.out.println("INTEGER");
}
```

This correctly determines 123 as integer, and both 123.45 and 123.0 as floats.

Comment: It does work, but it excludes the fact that it can still be `Long`/`Double`.

Comment: did u find a way?

Answer (score -1):

use something like, and so if return json object is an instance of float or integer you can then apply the required get:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jString);
Object aObj = jObj.get("a");
if(aObj instanceof Integer){
    System.out.println(aObj);
}
```

Comment: This does not work since `jObj.get("a")` returns `JsonElement` which is never `Integer` or `Float` (i.e. `Integer` is not a child of `JsonElement`).

Comment: This is a direct copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15920281/3271729). At least link give credit to the original answer

Comment: Additionally, this answer uses `org.json.simple.*` and not Gson.