# How to check the TypeOf value coming in Json Response?

Tags: android, json

I am getting `JSON` Response which have a key `studentScore`.

First time it comes `studentScore="102"` and,

Second time it comes like `studentScore  = 101`.

So, My Question is how Can I detect every time which type of value is coming? 
for example integer or string.

so, how can i figure out about this in android using JsonObjects?

Comment: Does it make a difference for you?

Comment: I think it will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the type of a value from a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject)