# Receiving JSON data in Java Object

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to store `replies` data :

```
replies : {
  "kind": "Listing",
  "data": "Foobar"
}
```

and I have created the following object structure to store the above JSON in Java:

```
class Replies {
  private String kind;
  private String data;
}
```

But the problem is, there are some cases (when data fields are null values) in which the `replies` object returns:

```
replies : ""
```

When this happens, it throws error because it cannot store `String` in `replies` object. What should I do to counter this issue?

Edit: Maybe my wording of the question a little confusing. My question boils down to: How can I create class `Replies` to not only receive `Replies` object (when the object is nonempty) but also `String` (when the object is empty)?

Comment: You say that "it appears as"; please provide more detail about this case. In general, switching between returning a JSON string and a JSON object in a case like this is extremely unfriendly behavior and should be changed if possible.

Comment: Check out [How to check the type of a value from a JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920212/how-to-check-the-type-of-a-value-from-a-jsonobject)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Yes, I agree. Let me rephrase it: "when ```Replies``` object is empty (in REST response), it returns ```replies : ""```, resulting in problem when trying to map it into ```Replies``` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Replies {

private String kind;
private String data;



Replies(String data,String kind){
    this.data=data;
    this.kind=kind;
}

Replies(String kind){
    this.kind=kind;
}

}
```

and in onCreate()

```
 Replies replies;

if(data==null){

 replies = new Replies(kind);

 }else{

   replies = new Replies(data,kind);
  }
```

Comment: It's not just data field being null. It's the whole replies object itself being a String obj, instead of ```Replies``` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the length of the JSON obtained (replies), and for example, if its length is greater than 4 chars, then it must has data, and do your code then, otherwise, It's less than or equals 4 chars, then it means that the JSON is having very short length, which would be an indicator not to use that JSON.

Comment: I don't think this is optimal. Yes I can do something quick and dirty but I want to do it without resorting to some tricks.

Comment: Well,  If you do not want to workaround with the obtained JSON, the only solution that comes to me, is to let the backend handle the issue, as Backend is not supposed to return empty replies.